# How to create partitioned BigQuery table in Java

Tags: google-bigquery

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables shows how to create partitioned table in Python. I've been there, I've done that.

Now the question is, how to do the same thing with Java API? What is the corresponding Java code doing the same thing as the Python one below:

```
{
  "tableReference": {
    "projectId": "myProject",
    "tableId": "table1",
    "datasetId": "mydataset"
  },
  "timePartitioning": {
    "type": "DAY"
  }
}
```

Java with missing partitioning:

```
Job createTableJob = new Job();
JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = new JobConfiguration();
JobConfigurationLoad loadConfiguration = new JobConfigurationLoad();

createTableJob.setConfiguration(jobConfiguration);
jobConfiguration.setLoad(loadConfiguration);

TableReference tableReference = new TableReference()
    .setProjectId("myProject")
    .setDatasetId("mydataset")
    .setTableId("table1");

loadConfiguration.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
// what should be place here to set DAY timePartitioning?
```

I'm using the newest api version from Maven Central Repository: `com.google.apis:google-api-services-bigquery:v2-rev326-1.22.0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

Example Java code:

```
String projectId = "";
String datasetId = "";

Table content = new Table();
TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning();
timePartitioning.setType("DAY");
timePartitioning.setExpirationMs(1L);
content.setTimePartitioning(timePartitioning);

Bigquery.Tables.Insert request = bigquery.tables().insert(projectId, datasetId, content);
Table response = request.execute();
```

Answer (score 4):

Please let me share a more updated way to create partitioned tables (works with Java API 0.32):

```
Schema schema = Schema.of( newFields);
TimePartitioning timePartitioning = TimePartitioning.of(TimePartitioning.Type.DAY);
TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.newBuilder()
        .setSchema(schema)
        .setTimePartitioning(timePartitioning)
        .build();

TableId tableId = TableId.of(projectName, datasetName, tableName)
TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder( tableId, tableDefinition).build();
bigQuery.create( tableInfo);
```

**Update on 19/03/2018:**

To load some data into a specific partition (or to insert the result as a Select into a specific partition), you just have to add the day of this partition (using the suffix: $yyyymmdd) to the name of the table when you construct the *TableId* object. Here is an example:

```
private void runJob(JobConfiguration jobConf) {
    BIG_QUERY.create(JobInfo.of(jobConf));
}

private TableId getTableToOverwrite(String tableToOverwrite, String partition) {
    return TableId.of(PROJECT, DATASET, tableToOverwrite  + "$" + partition);
}

void loadInDayPartition(String dayUrl, String dayPartition) {

    LoadJobConfiguration loadConf = LoadJobConfiguration.newBuilder(getTableToOverwrite(TABLE_LEGACY, dayPartition),
            dayUrl, FormatOptions.avro())
            .build();

    runJob(loadConf);
}
```

I don't have any example to insert data in streaming into a partition table, but I guess it is similar.

Comment: Can you please also update regarding writing data to BigQuery partitioned Table ?

Comment: @Sourygna, how have you found this one? Is there any official documentation about it? Or did you guess it with this page for instance: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data

Comment: @chaiyachaiya if I remember well, I think I was not able to find the answer on the BQ documentation or in the API documentation, and I ended up opening the Google's code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to partition by field, the code would look like as below.

```
Schema schema = Schema.of( fields);
Builder timeParitioningBuilder = TimePartitioning.newBuilder(TimePartitioning.Type.DAY);
timeParitioningBuilder.setField("partition_column");
TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.newBuilder()
        .setSchema(schema)
        .setTimePartitioning(timePartitioning)
        .build();

TableId tableId = TableId.of(projectName, datasetName, tableName)
TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder( tableId, tableDefinition).build();
bigQuery.create( tableInfo);
```